# Is there an equivalent to Jason Randolph's Super Duper mode vim re-mapping for Linux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, optimization

I'm very interested in moving from my Mac to a Linux system. The main barrier is my dependence on [Jason Rudolph's Keyboard](https://github.com/jasonrudolph/keyboard). Specifically, I need an equivalent to [(S)uper (D)uper Mode](https://github.com/jasonrudolph/keyboard#super-duper-mode). Super Duper activates vim-like keybindings when the keys "s" and "d" are pressed simultaneously. So j becomes ⬇️ and k becomes ⬆️. Is there anything like this built for linux?

After doing some research, I found [XCAPE](https://github.com/alols/xcape) and [caps2esc](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc) for remapping caps-lock. I also found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585643/is-there-an-equivalent-of-hammerspoon-macos-for-linux) about a hammerspoon equivalent. I have yet to find anything that implements Super Duper like functionality.

Comment: You will probably have to explain more what it is. Must people here will not have heard of it. But may may be able to answer the question if they knew what it is.

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching for this for many years an finally found a solution. It's based in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403671). On Arch Linux I had to install [interception tools](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools), and it seems to be available in most distros. Once that is done, I cloned down the [chorded keymap](https://gitlab.com/wsha/chorded_keymap) plugin, created a basic systemd service to run it as root and now I have Super Duper mode!

My systemd service which I stored at `/etc/systemd/system/super-duper.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Service to enable super duper mode
 
[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/vik/dotfiles/chorded_keymap
ExecStart=/home/vik/dotfiles/chorded_keymap/run.sh
Restart=always
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My little `run.sh` script - note your keyboard might have a different DEVNODE:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DEVNODE=/dev/input/event4

intercept -g $DEVNODE | python /home/vik/dotfiles/chorded_keymap/chorded_keymap.py | uinput -d $DEVNODE
```